# Cometd listener callback not being triggered in AngularJS Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, cometd

I am trying to write a cometd angularjs service. When a cometd message that should trigger a callback happens, the callback is never called.

In the service, I collect the code to connect to a cometd server, and expose 'subscribe', 'unsubscribe', 'send', 'listen', 'removeListener' and 'leave' functions. In 'subscribe', 'unsubscribe', 'listen' and 'removeListener', I also record the subscriptions and listeners in the service so that they can be remade if the connection is broken. Here is the code of 'listen' and 'removeListener':

```
var listeners = {}; //Each property, named 'channel', contains an array
                    //containing listener, channel, callback


listen: function(channel, callBack) {
    console.log("add listener for " + channel + " called");
    var lis = cometd.addListener(channel, callBack);
    listeners[channel] = [lis, channel, callBack];

    return lis;
},

removeListener: function(lis) {

    var lis = false;
    lis = listeners[channel][0];
    delete listeners[channel];

    if(lis) {
    cometd.removeListener(lis);
    }
},
```

From a controller, I include my cometdService and then listen to a service channel. My callback function looks like this:

```
CometdService.listen("/service/messages", function(msg) {

    console.log("CometdService for /service/messages with msg.data: " + msg.data);
$scope.messages.append(msg.data);
});
```

the hope being that messages sent to the /service/messages channel for this client will be appended to $scope.messages, which is a div in my template.

However that never happens. I can see connection being made with the cometd server, and I can see the callback being registered:

```
add listener for /service/messages called  CometdService.js:129:6
09:37:55.737 Adding listener on /service/messages with scope undefined and callback function LoggedInCtrl/listener<()  cometd.js:1275:17
09:37:55.738 Added listener Object { channel: "/service/messages", scope: undefined, callback: LoggedInCtrl/listener<(), listener: true, id: 0 }  cometd.js:1275:17
```

Almost immediately, I see the listener being deleted and then readded:

```
09:37:56.229 Removed listener Object { 0: "/service/messages", 1: 0, channel: "/service/messages", scope: undefined, callback: LoggedInCtrl/listener<(), listener: true, id: 0 }  cometd.js:1275:17
09:37:56.231 Adding listener on /service/messages with scope undefined and callback function LoggedInCtrl/listener<()  cometd.js:1275:17
09:37:56.232 Added listener Object { channel: "/service/messages", scope: undefined, callback: LoggedInCtrl/listener<(), listener: true, id: 1 }  cometd.js:1275:17
```

I then see the message from the server being received:

```
09:37:56.310 Transport websocket received websocket message message { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, data: "[{"data":"{\"msg\":\"Hello\"}","channel":"/server/messages"}]", origin: "ws://localhost:8080", lastEventId: "", ports: Object, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false } Object { envelopes: Object[3], timeouts: Object[3], webSocket: WebSocket }
```

But I never see the callback being called.

Any help appreciated;

Comment: Please add your `cometd.configure()` part.

Comment: What type of object is `$scope.messages`? Where is its `append` method defined?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add/remove listeners when the connection is broken, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_subscribe_vs_listen).

Listeners are added when you configure the application *before* the handshake, and remain there until you explicitly remove them.
You may want to add/remove listeners based on your application logic, but don't do it - like you say - to cope with the fact that the connection is broken - it is not needed and it's unnecessary work on your part.

Subscribers should be added in a `/meta/handshake` successful listener, also explained in the documentation linked above. This guarantees that subscribers are automatically removed and re-added by CometD upon rehandshakes - again no need for an application to do anything.

You also want to read the [section on dynamic resubscription](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_subscribe_resubscribe).

The logging you report from your application tells that there is something wrong that your application does: the listener should not be deleted and re-added like your logs show - this is something your application does, not CometD.

I recommend that you simplify your application following the advices above; most likely your problem will go away.